# generar la suma de columnas con PANDAS pyhton

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

tengo mi funcion, la cual hago la suma de todas la columnas inicializadas en 0 para obtener lo que trae la variable, sin embargo cuando llamo la funcion me corre un espacio en la fila y no me suma el contador total monto credito, me puede ayudar. aca ejemplo del archivo generado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

'''
#comienza la clase de calcular y sumar totales

```
def calcular_y_actualizar_totales(sheet, last_row_for_sum, resumenes):
orgs = ["720", "722", "744", "860", "872"]
# Inicializa las variables de suma
suma_doe_contador = 0
suma_doe_monto = 0
suma_dbnc_contador = 0
suma_dbnc_monto = 0
suma_dp_contador = 0
suma_dp_monto = 0
suma_voe_contador = 0
suma_voe_monto = 0
suma_vbnc_contador = 0
suma_vbnc_monto = 0
suma_moe_contador = 0
suma_moe_monto = 0
suma_mbnc_contador = 0
suma_mbnc_monto = 0
suma_debito_total_contador = 0
suma_debito_total_sum_monto = 0
suma_credito_total_contador = 0
suma_credito_total_sum_monto = 0
suma_total_contador = 0
suma_total_sum_monto = 0

# Realiza la suma sucesiva en las variables de suma
for resumen in resumenes:
    suma_doe_contador += resumen.doeContador
    suma_doe_monto += resumen.doeMonto
    suma_dbnc_contador += resumen.dbncContador
    suma_dbnc_monto += resumen.dbncMonto
    suma_dp_contador += resumen.dpContador
    suma_dp_monto += resumen.dpMonto
    suma_voe_contador += resumen.voeContador
    suma_voe_monto += resumen.voeMonto
    suma_vbnc_contador += resumen.vbncContador
    suma_vbnc_monto += resumen.vbncMonto
    suma_moe_contador += resumen.moeContador
    suma_moe_monto += resumen.moeMonto
    suma_mbnc_contador += resumen.mbncContador
    suma_mbnc_monto += resumen.mbncMonto
    suma_debito_total_contador += resumen.debito_total_contador
    suma_debito_total_sum_monto += resumen.debito_total_sum_monto
    suma_credito_total_contador += resumen.creditototal_contador
    suma_credito_total_sum_monto += resumen.creditototal_sum_monto
    suma_total_contador += resumen.total_sum_contador
    suma_total_sum_monto += resumen.total_sum_monto

# Escribir la suma al final de los datos
sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=6, value=suma_doe_contador) # type: ignore
sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=7, value=suma_doe_monto) # type: ignore 
sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=8, value=suma_dbnc_contador) # type: ignore
sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=9, value=suma_dbnc_monto) # type: ignore
sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=10, value=suma_dp_contador) # type: ignore
sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=11, value=suma_dp_monto) # type: ignore
sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=12, value=suma_voe_contador) # type: ignore
sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=13, value=suma_voe_monto) # type: ignore
sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=14, value=suma_vbnc_contador) # type: ignore
sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=15, value=suma_vbnc_monto) # type: ignore
sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=16, value=suma_moe_contador) # type: ignore
sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=17, value=suma_moe_monto) # type: ignore
sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=18, value=suma_mbnc_contador) # type: ignore
sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=19, value=suma_mbnc_monto) # type: ignore
if orgs == "720":
    sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=20, value=suma_debito_total_contador) 
    sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=21, value=suma_debito_total_sum_monto)
    sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=22, value=suma_credito_total_contador)
    sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=23, value=suma_credito_total_sum_monto) 
    sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=24, value=suma_total_contador)
    sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=25, value=suma_total_sum_monto) 
elif orgs in ["722", "744", "872"]:
        sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=18, value=suma_debito_total_contador)
        sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=19, value=suma_debito_total_sum_monto)
        sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=20, value=suma_credito_total_contador)
        sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=21, value=suma_credito_total_sum_monto) 
        sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=22, value=suma_total_contador)
        sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=23, value=suma_total_sum_monto)
else:
        sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=20, value=suma_credito_total_contador)
        sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=21, value=suma_debito_total_sum_monto)
        sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=22, value=suma_credito_total_contador)
        sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=23, value=suma_credito_total_sum_monto) 
        sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=24, value=suma_total_contador) 
        sheet.cell(row=last_row_for_sum, column=25, value=suma_total_sum_monto)
```

'''

esto me genera un archivo excel con mas del 10000 mil filas de datos, pero al finalizar la suma de estas columnas me genera en una columna con el valor 0 de la suma cuando se tienen datos.